# Nested foreach loops, PHP, how do I manipulate the values?

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

```
foreach ($bing_array as $bing_array_val)
{       
    foreach ($final_array as $final_array_val)
    {
        if ($final_array_val["link"] == $bing_array_val["link"])
        {

            $final_array_val["rank"] += $bing_array_val["rank"];
        }
    }
}
```

The above code has two foreach loops, which are nested.

It should test every bing_array["link"] against every final_array["link"] and if they are the same, the final_array["rank"] value should be += bing_array["rank"] but when I echo final_array, the ["rank"] values are unchanged.

I assume this is a syntax problem, where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Show us `$bing_array` and `$final_array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the reference syntax (`&` prefix):

```
foreach ($final_array as &$final_array_val)
{
}
unset($final_array_val);
```

Note that the `unset` is required to break the reference to the last value.  Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Wow, I didn't need that for a lot of the echo statements, but it works now for manipulations!

Is that required when manipulating the referenced array, rather than printing it?

I recognise & from C++

Comment: You only need it if you are going to modify the value.  Notice that I didn't suggest you do it for `bing_array`, since you are not modifying it.

Comment: Thanks, seeing as the parent foreach will call the child foreach several times, and presumably create and unset the reference variable several times, should I unset it after the parent foreach loop instead of immediately after the child foreach? Thanks!

Comment: You would only need to do it once, after the outer loop.  The variable can only point to one place at a time, so there is no need to unset it if you are just going to set it again.  But it wouldn't hurt.  It's generally clearer to read code when a value is cleaned up straight away.

Comment: Thanks Paddy, I will go with the more efficient unsetting after the parent loop.

Can my foreach loop affect global variable normally, for example I would like to set a boolean variable $found=true when a match is found using the IF statement in my above code.

Comment: Yes, you can.  That's one of the things I hate about PHP - the ability to make a new variable that persists outside the scope block in which it was created.  I come from a C and C++ background, so I still define the variable at the scope level I want it (*ie* before the loops).  That makes it clear to any readers that I intended the variable to be used outside of the loops.  It's also good practice just in case your arrays are empty and you never loop.  You can still guarantee the variable has a value and you don't have to use `isset`.

Comment: Thanks Paddy, this has helped a lot, I was at this for hours assuming it was a syntax error rather than a scope error. You are right, PHP does seem to maintain mostly global variables, so this one threw me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the actual code you need :

```
foreach ($bing_array as &$bing_array_val)
{       
    foreach ($final_array as &$final_array_val)
    {
        if ($final_array_val["link"] == $bing_array_val["link"])
        {
            $final_array_val["rank"] += $bing_array_val["rank"];
        }
    }
    unset(&$final_array_val);
}
unset(&$bing_array_val);
```

In your initial code, each time you were looping on $final_array, it was creating a temporary value called $final_array_val containing the content. Then, you modified it, and then it was replaced for each occurence of the foreach.

By passing the variables by reference, instead of creating a new temporary variable in the foreach, you use the actual variable which will keep the modifications you have done to it.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, I was able to crack it with @paddy 's answer but this is what I made, thanks! I understand reference variables from C++ so will be able to continue!